# Dynamical use of setIcon() on default alertDialogs?

Tags: android, icons, set, uri, android-alertdialog

Is there a way to dynamically set the icon displayed on a default alertDialog box without needing to create a custom one? For example, i would like for the following alertDialog, the method setIcon() to display the image i provide using a uri variable with a path stored inside.

```
private void showProductInfo(){
    MyProduct myProduct= (MyProduct) myProductGoldenRetriever();
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Product Information");
    alertDialog.setMessage(myProduct.getMyProductInfo());
    alertDialog.setButton("Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           showPrompt();
       }
    });
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.default_img);//<--Here Need to Provide a different image each time
    alertDialog.show();
}//endOfShowProductInfo
```

Is this somehow possible or do i need to create a custom alertDialog using an appropriate .xml layout file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to set the icon to a Drawable created from a Uri? I'm going to assume `MyProduct` has a `getUri()` method. If not, just modify it accordingly:

```
Resources res = getResources();
BitmapDrawable icon = new BitmapDrawable(res, myProduct.getUri().toString());
alertDialog.setIcon(icon);
```

The [`BitmapDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html) class has a constructor that takes in the resources and a String representing the file path. If you're using a Uri, you can just convert it using `toString()`. The [`AlertDialog.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html) class has an overloaded `setIcon()` method that takes in a Drawable. Just create your drawable from your path, and set it as your dialog icon. This isn't tested (no Eclipse here) but should work.

Comment: You understood correctly, plus your suggestion seems very promising. But when i ve tried it in different ways i couldn't fix it. For example i tried BitmapDrawable icon=new BitmapDrawble(res,"R.drawable.default_img"); for an img in my drawable directory. Then i tried a full path to an image like: "/Users/Admin/Desktop/default_img.png" didn't work either :/

Comment: If your files are already in your drawable folder, just change default_img to the icon you want. And in your MyProduct class, instead of a setUri and getUri, just use an int to store a resource id, e.g. setResourceId(R.drawable.image1). Then just use `setIcon(myProduct.getResourceId())`;. On your second example, you're trying to pull an image from your PC. You can't do this. That's not a full path anyway, a full path would be something like C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/default_img.png.

Comment: I ll stick with the tactic you ve just mentioned. Concerning the second example of mine, i use a mac :) Thank you very much for your time and your interest.

Comment: You're welcome! Heh, thought the path looked slightly different than usual. :P